# Counting inspired from 100 prisoners problem

Tags: probability, combinatorics

Suppose there are $100$ boxes in which we place labels $1,\dots, 100$ in some random manner and fix this for the rest of the discussion of this problem. Next one of those $100$ labels are assigned to a person and this choice is fixed.

Now the person is allowed to choose $50$ random boxes. What is the probability that one of those 50 chosen boxes contains the labels assigned to the person? It is just

$\displaystyle{\frac{\binom{99}{49}}{100\choose 50}}=0.5$

Can one also count this alternatively:

Suppose there are $100$ boxes in which we place labels $1,\dots,100$ in some random manner and fix this for the rest of the discussion of this problem. Next a person is allowed to choose $50$ random boxes and then this choice is also fixed.

Now the person is allowed to choose one of those 100 labels. What is the probability that one of those $50$  chosen boxes contains the labels chosen by the person?

Total number of ways to choose a label is $100$. Out of these the desirable ones are only 50. So probability is $\frac{50}{100}=0.5$

Are both ways of counting same? Are both problems same? It is a bit non-obvious to me how both are the same problem but intuition says yes. Please suggest a technical answer. A small voice in my mind is nagging me that both ways are not counting the same thing. Only the answer ends up being same. Somehow by considering different orderings of things we are considering 2 different problems. I think some rigorous mathematical use of addition/multiplication principle and the choose function is needed.

Comment: They are effectively the same when considering a single person, yes.  Once you go on to more than one prisoner getting to choose however and trying to keep the flavor the same as the classic problem, you need to keep aware of the dependence of what numbers each prisoner is allowed to choose.  In the classic problem, the prisoners are all assigned their respective numbers in such a way as to have no repeated numbers.  Changing the order in which choices are made or by whose will choices are made will generally not cause major differences in the problem.

Comment: It is worth pointing out that the classic problem goes on to ask for an optimal strategy and subsequently the probability that *all* prisoners find their respective desired number within fifty guesses, and random guessing is not at all the ideal strategy for them to follow.  The calculations you are doing here don't come into play when considering the true optimal strategy.

Comment: @JMoravitz Yes I changed the title to reflect that. The original problem needs to count cyclic permutations.